# How do I release (forced, if necessary) 9-patch (NinePatchDrawable) from memory in Android?

Tags: android

How Do You Force A NinePatchDrawable to release the BitMap bytes it parsed out of 'res'?

---

As an Android developer I face pressure to control memory utilization in my games.

I work to control memory utilization by releasing resources as quickly as I can after they are no longer used. To this end, I maintain a list of all loaded resources and purge / release them from memory as soon as I am done with them.

My application uses a number of different types of graphical resources

- BitMap
- BitMapDrawable
- Drawable
- NinePatchDrawable

How do I release these objects right now?

- BitMap : I use the "recycle()" method
- BitMapDrawable : I use the "getBitMap().recycle()" method
- Drawable : I set these to null (not working)
- NinePatchDrawable : I set these to null (not working)

What have you tried?

- You cannot "getBitmap()" a NinePatchDrawable
- You cannot convert a NinePatchDrawable to a BitMapDrawable (even if they are both Bitmap based Drawables)
- There seems to be a way to parse the PNG yourself, feeding the bytes into NinePathDrawable yourself -- this might get me to a point where I can just "recycle()" the underlying BitMap myself, but that seems like I'm reinventing the wheel (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13542)

My Current Rules:

- Never use @drawable/ in XML
- Never android:background in XML
- Never android:src in XML

Comment: What evidence do you have that you need to actually worry about the 9-patches? Have you used MAT and determined that they are tying up substantial heap space? FWIW, I have no solution for proactively getting rid of a 9-patch. Then again, I'm surprised that a game developer is using them in the first place, since I'm not aware that they have a role in OpenGL or `Canvas` use.

Comment: @CommonsWare: very fair questions. I used the techniques I learned at Google IO (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) using MAT to determine that *part* of my problem is the nine patches. Using 'recycle()' and 'getBitmap().recycle()' on my other drawable resources has drastically reduced the situation, but on some of my devices I'm still getting VM allocation errors. I was hoping to achieve consistent Bitmap behavior (free them all the same way.)

Comment: @CommonsWare: My games (which are not very sophisticated) use a mix of Canvas and Activities (decorated with nine patches.)  These memory problems occur when the player leaves the Android Activity and then requests that Canvas allocate lots of memory before the OS reclaims the resources in the terminating Activity. There are many solutions (I think) beyond freeing memory faster - I could use loading screens, or not use so many nine patches in the Activities (scale Bitmaps instead.)

Comment: You've probably already done this, but have you added a manual `System.gc()` call before the "Canvas allocate[s] lots of memory"? Android's GC is not especially aggressive, in the interests of CPU time, but it might help.

Comment: I wish I could mark this comment as an answer. One solution seems to be allowing the Activity to terminate and then calling System.gc() later in the application to reclaim the nine-patches. Timing this call and monitoring different configurations in MAT is critical to finding the right place to call it in your Canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use: @drawable/, android:background, android:src in xml, you can always use custom classes.

So instead of
`<ImageView android:src="@drawable/bg" />`
you can use: 
`<com.myPackage.CustomImageView android:src="@drawable/bg" />`

Than in the CustomImageView in the constructor you can get the references to your xml attributes:

```
    
private Drawable bg2;
private Drawable bg1;
public void CustomImageView(Context context, Attrs attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);

    // Use this to get references to your xml attributes
    int resourceId = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue("android", "src", 0);
    bg1 = getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);

    // Or for the 'background' attribute
    resourceid = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue("android", "background", 0);
    bg2 = getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);

    // Now you can recycle() your 'bg' whenever you're done
}
```

This way, you can extract references from your xml. And recycle() them when you think it's appropriate

Comment: I'm working on getting this code to function and testing ... thank you for your answer, I'll be back!

Comment: you can always post your own 'best answer', and mark that one as the correct answer. I think it might be confusing for user who read this answer, but miss your comment. So i suggest to post your own answer, and mark that one as the correct one

Answer (score 1):

I too am frustrated by the outofmemory bug. My application was throwing an outofmemory error whenever the user went from one activity to another. Setting my drawables to null and calling `System.gc()` didn't work, neither did recycling my bitmapDrawables with `getBitMap().recycle()`. Android would continue to throw the outofmemory error with the first approach, and it would throw a canvas error message whenever it tried using a recycled bitmap with the second approach.

I took an even third approach. I set all views to null and the background to black.  I do this cleanup in my onStop() method. This is the method that gets called as soon as the activity is no longer visible. The onDestroy() method might not get called. Also, if the cleanup is done in the onPause() method, users will get a black screen before moving onto the next screen.

To prevent a black screen from occurring if the user presses the back button on the device, I then reload the activity in the onRestart() method by calling the startActivity(getIntent()) and then finish() methods.

Note: it's not really necessary to change the background to black.